# A matrix operation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am trying to simplify my code a bit, and I am across a small question.  Let

```
v  = [1; 2; 3];
a1 = [4; 5; 6];
a2 = [7; 8; 9];
A  = [a1, a2];
```

I am aiming to compute

```
u = [v.*a1, v.*a2]
```

by only using `v` one time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, you can do this using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), for example:

```
u = bsxfun(@times,A,v);
```

or also by using `repmat`

```
u= repmat(v,[1 2]).*A;
```

or also by using `kron`

```
u= kron(v,[1 1]).*A;
```

or last, just using matrix multiplication:

```
u = v*[1 1].*A;
```

I'm sure there are even more ways, but I'll stop here...