# Matlab: Fastest way replicate and multiply two vectors

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Let's say I have two vectors:

```
    A = [1 2 3];
    B = [10;20;30];
```

They could also be two line vectors - doesn't matter, I'll choose whatever is best. I now want to create a line vector by multiplying B with each element of A:

```
    C = [1*10;1*20;1*30;2*20;2*20;2*30;3*10;3*20;3*30];
```

This can easily and rather efficiently be done by using a tensor product `B*A` and reshaping it into a line vector. But is there a faster way? This happens inside a fitting function, so it would be possible to pass additional vectors like indexing arrays.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a bottleneck, because that sounds pretty efficient. Especially on a multi-core machine...

Comment: Even if it were the most time consuming part, it is likely not the point with most improvement potential (unless the remainder runs really quick).

Comment: possible duplicate of [A matrix operation in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532457/a-matrix-operation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised no-one has thought of this one yet:

```
C = bsxfun(@times, A,B);
C = C(:);
```

A small comparison (Win 7 64-bit, MATLAB R2010a 64-bit):

```
A = rand(1,1000);
B = rand(1000,1);

tic
D = kron(A.',B);
toc

tic
D2 = B*A;
D2 = D2(:);
toc

tic
D3 = bsxfun(@times, A,B);
D3 = D3(:);
toc

isequal(D,D2)
isequal(D,D3)
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.123301 seconds.  %// kron
Elapsed time is 0.034271 seconds.  %// B*A
Elapsed time is 0.010617 seconds.  %// bsxfun
ans =
     1
ans =
     1
```

Results with `A = rand(1,5000); B = rand(5000,1);` :

```
Elapsed time is 7.134506 seconds.  %// kron
Elapsed time is 0.119705 seconds.  %// B*A
Elapsed time is 0.162295 seconds.  %// bsxfun
```

It seems the algorithm underlying `kron` scales as O(N²) or worse...

Comment: +1! I'm surprised `kron` is that slow for larger matrices in MATLAB. I left my MATLAB computer now, but using [this online compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php), I get quite different results. Check my update.

Comment: I get quite consistent results with this answer. Surprising to see that `bsxfun` actually takes the cake,  In the range of size 100-10000 it is significantly faster than regular multiplication and using the processor much less in the meantime. However it does seem to scale a little less good so I suppose that depending on your hardware there is a switch to where `*` becomes faster.

Answer (score 4):

Fifth time I've answered with [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) the last two days:

```
kron(A',B)
   10
   20
   30
   20
   40
   60
   30
   60
   90
```

A time comparison with:

```
C = B*A;
C = C(:);
```

gives the following results:

```
t1 =  0.21601    % kron
t2 =  0.56776    % C = B*A
```

## Update:

I just left my MATLAB computer, so these results are obtained [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php):

```
A = rand(1,4000);
B = rand(4000,1);

tic
for ii = 1:10
D = kron(A',B);
end
t1 = toc

tic
for ii = 1:10
D2 = B*A;
D2 = D2(:);
end
t2 = toc

tic
for ii = 1:10
D3 = bsxfun(@times, A,B);
D3 = D3(:);
end
t3 = toc

sum(sum(abs(D-D2))) < 1e-10
sum(sum(abs(D-D3))) < 1e-10

t1 =  0.43138
t2 =  0.85762
t3 =  0.43332
ans =  1
ans =  1
```

Comment: Actually this appears to be slower than the originally proposed solution. Edit: Your timing does not seem to match mine, could you show the timing code?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Can you post your benchmark results? I don't get the same results...

Comment: What Matlab version do (both of) you use?

Comment: Is `kron` multithreaded? Because `*` is on later versions which means architecture could make a big difference

Comment: @Dan It appears that kron is also multi threaded. I have added my observations as a separate answer now.

Comment: Try that test again with `A = rand(1,5000);  B = rand(5000,1);`. I bet the outcomes will be quite different :)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: `kron` is not built-in (at least on R2010a). Looking at the code: explicit element-wise multiplication is performed on the two arrays, which are indexed with index vectors created with `meshgrid`. Element-wise multiplication is multithreaded, so `kron` is multithreaded, but the indexing method is (apparently) rather slow for larger vectors...

Comment: @RobertP.: The online version is Octave. I can't check this where I am, but it could be Octave has a different implementation of `kron`, does not use BLAS effectively for multiplications like these, has a different `bsxfun`, ... It's a different program, so it's like comparing elstars with braeburns :)

Comment: When running your updated code, `kron` is still lagging behind significantly, but surprisingly `bsxfun` beats the standard `*`!!

Comment: Back on MATLAB now. I get the same results as you @DennisJaheruddin. bsxfun is actually fastest!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I doubt whether there can be significant improvement in this case, because matrix multiplication is known to be the strength of Matlab and flattening an array is trivial, here is how I came to the conclusion that using kron won't help:

```
A = [1 2 3];
B = [10;20;30];

tic,C = B*A;C = C(:);toc % Typically takes about  0.000012 seconds
tic, C=kron(A',B);toc    % Typically takes about  0.000093 seconds
```

Of course this may change for different input sizes, but this is what I get from the question.

I don't think the matlab version will matter much but it was tested on 2012b.
It was tested with 12 cores. When using both solutions in a loop, 6 cores appeared to be used in each case so I don't think that is the 'problem' either.

Comment: I get figures which support yours, `0.000043 s` for the first version, `0.000167 s` for the second. Version R2013b on dual 4-core machine.